# Borel Measures: Sum Derivative

Tags: integration, general-topology, measure-theory

*Meanwhile I got it...*

Given a Borel space $\Omega$.

Consider Borel measures:
$$\mu_\lambda:\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\to\mathbb{C}:\quad\mu_\lambda\geq0$$

Does it admit densities:
$$\mu:\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\to\mathbb{C}:\quad\operatorname{d\mu_\lambda}=\rho_\lambda\operatorname{d\mu}$$
*(Counterexample?)*

Comment: You probably intend the reversed inclusion in your definition of $U < U'$, right? Also, you are assuming that the limit exists, correct?

Comment: Yes that was a typo thank you :) corrected - you know muscle memory ^^ hmm not necessarily no I don't assume that the limit exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given unit interval $\mathbb{I}$.

Consider Borel measures:
$$\mu_\infty:=\lambda\quad\mu_{s}:=\delta_s\quad(s\in\mathbb{I})\quad$$

Suppose Borel densities:
$$\operatorname{d\mu_\infty}=\rho_\infty\operatorname{d\mu}\quad\operatorname{d\mu_s}=\rho_s\operatorname{d\mu}$$

By absolute continuity:
$$\mu_s(s)\neq0\implies\mu(s)\neq0$$

For singletons:
$$0=\mu_\infty(s)=\rho_\infty(s)\mu(s)\implies\rho_\infty(s)=0$$

For unit interval:
$$1=\mu_\infty(\mathbb{I})=\int_\mathbb{I}\rho_\infty\operatorname{d\mu}=0$$
Contradiction!